# Connect Ejabbered via Mule ESB CE

Tags: xmpp, mule, ejabberd

I tried to put Ejabberd server at the back of Mule ESB community edition, that means all messages to Ejabberd server must go to ESB at first.

I used the xmpp connector in the document as following xml configure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xmpp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xmpp"
  xmlns:stdio="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.1/mule.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xmpp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xmpp/3.1/mule-xmpp.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio/3.1/mule-stdio.xsd">

    <xmpp:connector name="xmppConnector" host="192.168.1.132" port="5222" user="whh@whh.com" password="password"/>

    <flow name="stdio2xmpp">
        <stdio:inbound-endpoint system="IN"/>
        <xmpp:outbound-endpoint type="CHAT" recipient="sjc@whh.com"/>
    </flow>

    <flow name="xmpp2stdio">
        <xmpp:inbound-endpoint type="CHAT" from="sjc@whh.com"/>
        <xmpp:xmpp-to-object-transformer/>
        <stdio:outbound-endpoint system="OUT"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

I'm sure the username and password is correct, since I can use Pidgin to login the server with it. When I tried to run this flow in studio, it always throws the exception "not connected to server".

```
Exception in thread "main" org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentStartException: IllegalStateException: Not connected to server. 
        at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:174) 
        at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.start(ApplicationWrapper.java:107) 
        at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:47) 
        at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.run(ApplicationDeployer.java:56) 
        at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:88) 
        Caused by: org.mule.retry.RetryPolicyExhaustedException: Not connected to server. 
        at org.mule.retry.policies.AbstractPolicyTemplate.execute(AbstractPolicyTemplate.java:105) 
        at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.connect(AbstractConnector.java:1616) 
        at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.start(AbstractConnector.java:428) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) 
        at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:225) 
        at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager$RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:276) 
        at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.invokePhase(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:155) 
        at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:126) 
        at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:80) 
        at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:120) 
        at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:94) 
        at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:90) 
        at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.invokePhase(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:72) 
        at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:64) 
        at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:250) 
        at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:151) 
        ... 4 more 
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to server. 
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.addPacketListener(XMPPConnection.java:747) 
        at org.jivesoftware.smackx.ServiceDiscoveryManager.init(ServiceDiscoveryManager.java:270) 
        at org.jivesoftware.smackx.ServiceDiscoveryManager.(ServiceDiscoveryManager.java:80) 
        at org.jivesoftware.smackx.ServiceDiscoveryManager$1.connectionCreated(ServiceDiscoveryManager.java:66) 
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.initConnection(XMPPConnection.java:957) 
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPConnection.java:904) 
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:1415) 
        at org.mule.transport.xmpp.XmppConnector.connectToJabberServer(XmppConnector.java:137) 
        at org.mule.transport.xmpp.XmppConnector.doConnect(XmppConnector.java:84) 
        at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$5.doWork(AbstractConnector.java:1556) 
        at org.mule.retry.policies.AbstractPolicyTemplate.execute(AbstractPolicyTemplate.java:67) 
        ... 22 more
```

Anyone has idea for this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

mule it is build on the top of Smack which may experience issues with establishing connection.

Can you verify that xmpp server is up? Once you know it go ahead and debug Smack.
Smack connection init catches just subset of exceptions which may be thrown.
E.g. it would ignore NPE and claim that connection in OK.
It is also not thread safe, so prototype with only one connection to xmpp server.

Comment: I'm sure server is up. OK, i'll try to debug Smack in mule esb.